# Automatically insert parenthesis for method calls in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017, resharper

If I want to call a function/method in C++ my normal way is to type the first letters of the name and investigate the IntelliSense suggestions. If I choose one, the name will be inserted, but it would be great if also the parenthesis could be inserted. Of course the caret should be placed in the middle of the new parenthesis. I am using Visual Studio 2015 and ReSharper. Is there a setting in VS or R# about this?

eg

```
std::string s; 
s.em
```

the result after the use of IntelliSense should be

```
std::string s; 
s.empty(_CARET_);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VS2017 you can do the following to achieve the desired result:

- <kbd>s</kbd>
- <kbd>.</kbd>
- <kbd>e</kbd>
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>(</kbd>

Comment: Are you saying that to emulate the automatic addition of parentheses I have to press 5 buttons, or what?

Comment: No. He is saying that you could press "(" / "Shift+9" instead of Tab / Enter to insert the IntelliSense suggestion.
Until the functionality is added ( if ever ) to auto insert parenthesis after a function, this answer is very useful.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that having the cursor between parentheses for `empty` function makes sense since `empty` one has no parameters. But at the same time, having the cursor between parentheses for any function which has parameters is definitely handy. So, ReSharper C++ provides exactly this:

1. in case a function has no parameters

   - type `s.e`;
   - hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> to complete `empty` from the completion popup;
   - as a result, you will get `s.empty()_cursor_` and you can continue typing whatever you like after closing parenthesis.
2. in case a function has parameters (e.g. `append`)

   - type `s.a`;
   - hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> to complete `append` from the completion popup;
   - as a result, you will get `s.append(_cursor_)` and you can specify parameters.

Well, as you may see, ReSharper C++ locates the cursor depending on a function's signature.